# I need to refresh my view in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-2

When I click on `PatymentRecieved` left_menu link than we go to `PatymentRecieved` view and select shopId from shop dropDown ,basis of shopId we get customer name in another dropDown if we select any customer name from this customer dropdown than result generated in table though ajax response,The problem is that IFF we come to shopID dropdown than we select `="select"` also in customer name dropdown select `="Select"` than we need to refresh my view (table data ajax response)

```
public function selectCustById(){

        //check iff in shop dropDown shopId="Select"
       if($this->input->post('shopId')=="Select"){echo "<option>Select</option>";}

        $shop_id=$this->input->post('shopId');
        $data['custName']=$this->transaction_model->getCustNameByshopId();

        $i=0;

        foreach ($data['custName'] as $custName) {
            if($i==0){
                echo "<option>Select</option>";
                }
            echo "<option value='$custName->id'>$custName->name</option>";

             }
        $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the javascript code below after you select `"select"` in dropdown

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   window.location.reload(true);
```

above mentioned javascript will be used after checking value selected in both dropdown is "select".